# Compartor's compare method to compare double values

Tags: java, sorting, compare, comparator

I have to sort my response list by score,
But the score is double value and I tried to implement a compare method of Comparator class,
the response doesn't change much because of double difference becomes int value and ends up not sorting it,

Is there a way I can use this compare method for double or is there any other way I can sort my response by the score?

```
private List<MyResponseByScore> buildMyResponseByScore(MyreposneWithScore MyreposneWithScore) {
    return MyresposneWithScore.getAllScores().stream()
            .map(x -> new MyResponseByScore(
                    x.getAllOptions().getMayVal(),
                    (double) x.getMyScore(),
                    x.getAllOptions().getSomeVal()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).sort(new Comparator<MyResponseByScore>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyResponseByScore o1, MyResponseByScore o2) {
            if (o1.getScore() > o2.getScore()) {
                return o1.getScore() - o2.getScore();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: replace sort  ---use --
.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(MyResponseByScore::getScore))

Comment: If you want to compare `double` values for a `compare`/`compareTo` method, use [`Double.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much (much) simpler option would be to replace your own implementation of `Comparator` with `Comparator.comparingDouble(MyResponseByScore::getScore)`

That removes all the complexity of working out edge cases yourself. And it gives you easy access to elegant ways of changing the ordering such as `.reversed()`, `.thenComparing(...)` etc.